# How long does roll take to end?

Tags: dark-souls-2, dark-souls-2-sotfs

I mean The I-frames are based on how much ATT and ADP, but how long does it take (30 FPS frames) and (miliseconds) before you can act out (Do another roll, Attack, and other actions.) off a roll?

I'm assuming 20 frames, which is 2/3 of a second.

Comment: Note: I want to know both heavy, and light/mid.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the visual frames for the duration of the roll, but there is no difference between "light/mid/heavy" roll in DkS2. The only thing that encumbrance affects is the *distance* of the roll in total.

You can find more information about the roll mechanic, including roll speeds, Agility, Adaptability, and Encumbrance affect on the roll mechanic on the [wiki](http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/rolling)